# Log4Net is Not Working After code Obfuscation

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, visual-studio, log4net

I publish my WFP code and test the code the Log4Net show the log files and if it doesn't exists create it but after the code Obfuscation (using .NET Reactor follow the document) the Log4Net is not creating Log viewer files(Error.txt, Info.txt) and throw the exception `"Unexpected Error occur: Dispetcher.unhandledexception"`

Comment: The error you posted complains about an *unhandled exception*. This means nothing caught the exception, so nothing could log it. Did you add unhandled exception handlers to your code? Did you handle the [DispatcherUnhandledException](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.application.dispatcherunhandledexception?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=windowsdesktop-6.0) event?

Comment: Please post the message you get exactly as you get it. Your question is hard to understand, and has typos even in the parts that you could just copy.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos yes i already added the unhandled exception handlers but what i really wanna ask is that the log4net is not working after obfuscation...